# How do we query on array class for grouped objects in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have got a `sites` table and `credits` table. The associations for them are as follow:

```
# site.rb
has_many :credits

# credit.rb
belongs_to :site
```

I have grouped the credits by sites and want to get only credits for that site where amount is greater than 0.

Example:

```
Credits.all.group_by(&:site_id) # This will group credits by site
# {1=> #<Credit: id: 12017, amount: -0.1e2, 2=> #<Credit: id: 123, amount: 12>}
```

I tried with reject but it will through an error undefined method for an Array:

```
Credits.all.group_by(&:site_id).reject{|k,v| v.amount < 0}
# {2=> #<Credit: id: 123, amount: 12>}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using group instead of using group_by; the benefit is you will use SQL to do the grouping and filtering which is much faster than what you are doing now (group_by will make Rails fetch the entire collection and then use the ruby function to do the grouping and filtering)

So something like this

```
Credit.group(:site_id).having('amount > 0')
```

You will have to change your code though because this does not return a hash but a collection of ActiveRecord instances.

But if you want still want to use group_by use [filter](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_6_3/Hash/filter) instead

```
Credits.all.group_by(&:site_id).filter{|k,v| v.amount < 0}
```